# Can't start rails console in production

Tags: ruby-on-rails, sqlite, console

I'm getting this error when trying to start the rails console on my project:

```
/home/username/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p362/gems/activerecord-3.2.8/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_specification.rb:47:in `resolve_hash_connection': database configuration does not specify adapter (ActiveRecord::AdapterNotSpecified)
from /home/username/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p362/gems/activerecord-3.2.8/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_specification.rb:41:in `resolve_string_connection'
from /home/username/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p362/gems/activerecord-3.2.8/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_specification.rb:25:in `spec'
from /home/username/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p362/gems/activerecord-3.2.8/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_specification.rb:129:in `establish_connection'
from /home/username/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p362/gems/activerecord-3.2.8/lib/active_record/railtie.rb:82:in `block (2 levels) in <class:Railtie>'
from /home/username/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p362/gems/activesupport-3.2.8/lib/active_support/lazy_load_hooks.rb:36:in `instance_eval'
from /home/username/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p362/gems/activesupport-3.2.8/lib/active_support/lazy_load_hooks.rb:36:in `execute_hook'
from /home/username/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p362/gems/activesupport-3.2.8/lib/active_support/lazy_load_hooks.rb:43:in `block in run_load_hooks'
from /home/username/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p362/gems/activesupport-3.2.8/lib/active_support/lazy_load_hooks.rb:42:in `each'
from /home/username/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p362/gems/activesupport-3.2.8/lib/active_support/lazy_load_hooks.rb:42:in `run_load_hooks'
from /home/username/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p362/gems/activerecord-3.2.8/lib/active_record/base.rb:721:in `<top (required)>'
from /home/username/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p362/gems/activerecord-3.2.8/lib/active_record/railtie.rb:41:in `block in <class:Railtie>'
from /home/username/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p362/gems/railties-3.2.8/lib/rails/railtie.rb:179:in `call'
from /home/username/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p362/gems/railties-3.2.8/lib/rails/railtie.rb:179:in `block in load_console'
from /home/username/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p362/gems/railties-3.2.8/lib/rails/railtie.rb:179:in `each'
from /home/username/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p362/gems/railties-3.2.8/lib/rails/railtie.rb:179:in `load_console'
from /home/username/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p362/gems/railties-3.2.8/lib/rails/engine.rb:429:in `block in load_console'
from /home/username/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p362/gems/railties-3.2.8/lib/rails/application/railties.rb:8:in `each'
from /home/username/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p362/gems/railties-3.2.8/lib/rails/application/railties.rb:8:in `all'
from /home/username/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p362/gems/railties-3.2.8/lib/rails/engine.rb:429:in `load_console'
from /home/username/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p362/gems/railties-3.2.8/lib/rails/application.rb:153:in `load_console'
from /home/username/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p362/gems/railties-3.2.8/lib/rails/commands/console.rb:27:in `start'
from /home/username/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p362/gems/railties-3.2.8/lib/rails/commands/console.rb:8:in `start'
from /home/username/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p362/gems/railties-3.2.8/lib/rails/commands.rb:41:in `<top (required)>'
from script/rails:6:in `require'
from script/rails:6:in `<main>'
```

Here is my database.yml file (unmodified from the default one):

```
# SQLite version 3.x
#   gem install sqlite3
#
#   Ensure the SQLite 3 gem is defined in your Gemfile
#   gem 'sqlite3'
development:
  adapter: sqlite3
  database: db/development.sqlite3
  pool: 5
  timeout: 5000

# Warning: The database defined as "test" will be erased and
# re-generated from your development database when you run "rake".
# Do not set this db to the same as development or production.
test:
  adapter: sqlite3
  database: db/test.sqlite3
  pool: 5
  timeout: 5000

production:
  adapter: sqlite3
  database: db/production.sqlite3
  pool: 5
  timeout: 5000
```

I don't believe this is a system-specific issue since it occurs both on my development environment (Fedora 17 laptop) and production environment (Debian 6 VPS). On the VPS, nginx+unicorn starts and serves without issue in production. What might the cause be?

Comment: If you want to use the production env, try `RAILS_END=production rails c`.

Comment: It's RAILS_ENV, typo.
I usually put 'export RAILS_ENV=production' to .bashrc.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Instead of `rails console RAILS_ENV=production` :

Use `rails console production` or  shorter `rails c production`.

The value following the call to rails console will be taken as the environment, thus it thinks "RAILS_ENV=production" is the name of the environment it should use, instead of "production".